# How to compare two scalars generated by multiplication between matrix and vectors?

Tags: matrices

E.g. $\alpha = x'\Omega^{-1}1$

$\beta = x'\Omega^{-1}x$

$\gamma = 1'\Omega^{-1}1$

$x$ and "1" on the RHS are column vectors, $\Omega$ is an invertible matrix.

How can one compare the size of $\alpha^2$ and $\beta\gamma$?

Comment: You can start by writing down the square and the product.

Comment: How? the $x$ and $\Omega$ are not concrete values.

Comment: It's your job to motivate the question and provide information on background and context. If you don't do your job properly, people will ignore your question, and rightly so.